# Bourne Shell script doing the job but producing extra message

Tags: shell, sh

So, the script should take in a file extension and possibly multiple files to change their extensions. It works for most, but when the file has a space in it, it changes it and then says the file does not exist. Heres what I have...

```
#!/bin/sh
fileExtension="$1"
shift
oldName="$@"
extension=${oldName##*.}
totalFiles=$#
totalFiles=$(( totalFiles+1 ))

num=1
while [ $num -lt $totalFiles ]
do
   for i in "$oldName"
   do
      extension=${i##*.}
      if test -e "$i" then
          newName="${i%.*}.$fileExtension"
          if [ "$i" = "$newName" ]
          then
             :
          else
              mv "$i" "$newName"
          fi
      else
          echo "$i": No such file
      fi
      num=$(( num+1 ))
      shift
      done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate a string, as least not the way you are. `oldName` needs to be an array

```sh
# other stuff
oldName=("$@")
# other stuff
for i in "${oldName[@]}"
# other stuff
```

Comment: Well, trying to change it to that didn't work, it just created an abundance of errors.

Comment: Why not just `for i in "$@"` (or even `for i`, though personally I'd never write that in a script, for all it means the same thing)?  You can then avoid the `shift` in the body of the loop, too.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify it:

```
#!/bin/sh
fileExtension="$1"
shift
for file in "$@"
do
    extension=${file##*.}
    if [ -e "$file" ]
    then
        newName="${file%.*}.$fileExtension"
        if [ "$file" != "$newName" ]
        then mv "$file" "$newName"
        fi
    else
        echo "$file: No such file" >&2
    fi
done
```

Comment: So, you're right, I should have simplified it but it still reads a file with a space in the middle as two different files. I thought the extension part would take care of that but apparently not.

Comment: Since the script shown reads the command line arguments, the question may be 'How are you invoking the script?'  If the script is `testscript`, then running `testscript *` should pass each file name as a separate argument, even if the file name contains spaces.  The code shown would work correctly.  On the other hand, if you have another script invoking it, and its list of filenames isn't properly constructed (perhaps the other script contains `testscript $*` instead of the correct `testscript "$@"`), then you end up with file names that contain spaces being broken.

Comment: I'd consider writing `extension="${file##*.}"` simply because I'm very cautious about variables that might contain spaces.  However, some of that dates back to learning on the (original) Bourne shell in the early 80s, and I'm told that it isn't necessary.  However, that's the only line that isn't fully protected.  You can either run the script with `sh -x testscript` or add `set -x` at the top of the script to see how the shell is interpreting the script.

Answer (score 0):

I got it with this...

```
#!/bin/sh
fileExtension="$1"
shift
for file in "$@"
do
    if test -e "$file"
    then
    newName="${file%.*}.$fileExtension"
        if test "$file" = "$newName"
        then
        :
        else
            mv "$file" "${file%.*}.$fileExtension"
    fi
    else
        echo "$file": No such file >&2
    fi
done
```